# Identity of Gamma Function Integral

Tags: integration, proof-verification, gamma-function

Whilst messing around with the integral
$$\int_a^b \Gamma(z)dz$$
I accidentally found the identity
$$\int_a^b \Gamma(z)dz=\int_0^1 \frac{1}{z}\big[\Gamma(b+\ln(z))-\Gamma(a+\ln(z))\big]dz$$
But I am afraid that this identity may not be true, as when I tried to test it with $a=1$, $b=2$, Wolfram Alpha would not give me a value for the second part. Here is my derivation for this identity:

$$\int_a^b \Gamma(z)dz$$
$$=\int_a^b \int_0^\infty x^{z-1}e^{-x} dx dz$$
$$=\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{b-1}e^{-x}-x^{a-1}e^{-x}}{\ln(x)} dx dz$$

Now define the function $I(n)$ as
$$I(n)=\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{b-1}e^{-x}-x^{a-1}e^{-x}}{\ln(x)}n^{\ln(x)} dx$$
So that $I(0)=0$ and $I(1)=\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{b-1}e^{-x}-x^{a-1}e^{-x}}{\ln(x)} dx dz$. Then we have
$$I'(n)=\int_0^\infty (x^{b-1}e^{-x}-x^{a-1}e^{-x})n^{\ln(x)-1} dx$$
$$I'(n)=\frac{1}{n}\int_0^\infty (x^{b-1}e^{-x}-x^{a-1}e^{-x})n^{\ln(x)}dx$$ 
$$I'(n)=\frac{1}{n}\int_0^\infty (x^{b-1}e^{-x}-x^{a-1}e^{-x})x^{\ln(n)} dx$$
$$I'(n)=\frac{1}{n}\int_0^\infty x^{\ln(n)+b-1}e^{-x}-x^{\ln(n)+a-1}e^{-x} dx$$
$$I'(n)=\frac{1}{n}\int_0^\infty x^{\ln(n)+b-1}e^{-x}-x^{\ln(n)+a-1}e^{-x} dx$$
$$I'(n)=\frac{1}{n}\big[\Gamma(\ln(n)+b)-\Gamma(\ln(n)+a)\big]$$
And because of the previously stated values of $I(0)$ and $I(1)$, 
$$\int_a^b \Gamma(z)dz=I(1)-I(0)$$
$$\int_a^b \Gamma(z)dz=\int_0^1 I'(n) dn$$
$$\int_a^b \Gamma(z)dz=\int_0^1 \frac{1}{n}\big[\Gamma(\ln(n)+b)-\Gamma(\ln(n)+a)\big] dn$$

Can anyone expose the error in this derivation, or confirm that it is correct?

Comment: The $\Gamma$ function has simple poles at the non-positive integers, you cannot integrate the $\Gamma$ function on a path that goes **through** them. The given identity might hold if you add a principal value ($\text{PV}$, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value) before the integral $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{z}\left[\ldots\right]\,dz$.

Comment: How was it demonstrated that $n^{\ln(x)} = x^{\ln(n)}$?

Comment: @Leucippus That is a common identity.  Just take the log of both sides to see.

Comment: I see an error very early on.  $I(0)\ne0$.  Particularly, $0^y=+\infty\forall y<0$, so consider $y=\ln(x)$...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very early on, I spot an error:

$$I(0)\ne0$$

You probably were thinking that $0^{\text{anything}}=0$, but if $\text{anything}<0$, then we have a problem.

On the other hand, the derivative doesn't look so bad:

$$I'(t)=\frac{\Gamma(b+\ln(t))-\Gamma(a+\ln(t))}t$$

Taking the anti-derivative is easy by splitting parts and letting $u=\ln(t)$.

$$\int I'(t)~\mathrm dt=\int\Gamma(b+u)-\Gamma(a+u)~\mathrm du$$

So you can probably see that it relates directly back to the original integral very simply.